# Pass list of object from view to controller via jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I am having a challenge passing an object list from my view to my controller using ajax. My solution is an asp.net mvc 5 project. The object always comes out as null in the controller
First I create a view model like this below

```
public class policyDetailsViewModel
{

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public int message_code { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public List<Mypolicydetail> myPolicyDetails { get; set; }
        public List<Proposerdetail> proposerDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class Mypolicydetail
    {
        public Nullable<long> polCode { get; set; }
        public string polMaturityDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Proposerdetail
    {
        public Nullable<long> prpCode { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> clntCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Also, I have created my view as below

```
@model List<policyDetailsViewModel.Rootobject>

@if (Model != null){

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{    
   List<policyDetailsViewModel.Mypolicydetail> p_detail = Model[i].data.myPolicyDetails;
   for (int j = 0; j < p_detail.Count; j++)
     {
     
      <button class="btn btn-primary s" id="@p_detail[j].polCode" data-pdetail="@p_detail">Test @p_detail[j].polCode  </button>
}
}
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $(document).on("click", ".btn.btn-primary.s", function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var p = $(this).attr('data-pdetail');
        
        $.ajax({
            //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            url: '/client/policySummaryPreview',
            data: { "vm": p },
            success: function (res) {
                psummodal.find("#prv1").empty();
                psummodal.find("#prv1").html(res);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                //alert('errorLoad');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Finally my controller looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult policySummaryPreview(List<policyDetailsViewModel.Mypolicydetail> vm)
    {
        try
        {
            
            return PartialView("_partialPolicySummary");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My challenge is the `List<policyDetailsViewModel.Mypolicydetail> vm` is coming out null.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Debug and tell us what is in Exeption ex

Comment: There is nothing in Exception ex. Please see screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmdyz.png

Comment: In screenshot, vm is empty,that means your ajax dosnt send any thing.can you post _partialPolicySummary code?

Comment: @mostafakhoramnia, _partialPolicySummary is not the problem. Like you mentioned, the ajax is sending nothing. I have posted the view that displays the data before the ajax call. I suspect am not doing something right on that view.

Comment: Ok,before ajax write console.log(p) to see what is in p, absolutely p is the problem

Comment: p has portal.sCentral.ViewModels.policyDetailsViewModel+Mypolicydetail. see screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPkqa.png

Comment: So try string p_detail = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model[i].data.myPolicyDetails)) and see console.log(p) but its better to use id instead of setting whole object and sending it to server

Comment: @mostafakhoramnia, string p_detail = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model[i].data.myPolicyDetails)) is coming out well, and am able to deserialise it aso When I send only the Id, I will have to make a call to db to get the info that is in the object. Please advice me, which option is better.

Comment: Absolutely id and one simple select query to db is much better,cleaner,smarter and more professional